# Android: ActionBar glitch on show and hide

Tags: android, android-actionbar, show-hide

I would like to show/hide the action bar upon a click.

It does show and hide but it is not smooth...the bottom part hides but a different background for a little while before disappearing.

I even tried it in a simple hello world app and the result is the same.
Here's the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shit);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActionBar().hide();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use overlay mode instead of showing and hiding the actionbar.

From the [actionbar documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing):

> Beware that hiding and removing the action bar causes your activity to
>   re-layout in order to account for the space consumed by the action
>   bar. If your activity regularly hides and shows the action bar (such
>   as in the Android Gallery app), you might want to use overlay mode.
>   Overlay mode draws the action bar on top of your activity layout
>   rather than in its own area of the screen. This way, your layout
>   remains fixed when the action bar hides and re-appears. To enable
>   overlay mode, create a theme for your activity and set
>   android:windowActionBarOverlay to true. For more information, see the
>   section about [Styling the Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style).