# What is a clean way to hide and show ActionBar without a glitchy animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-animation

I have an activity with a tabbed `ViewPager`, containing five pages. The tabs are shown in the bottom of the screen.

Four of these pages are supposed to show custom `ActionBars`, one isn't.

I know when a page is chosen and can react to it by calling `Actionbar.show()` and `Actionbar.hide()` respectively. However, this makes the bottom of my activity glitch up and down for a second, because the layout seems to be redrawn or something. For a second I can see a "white background *behind* my actual background color" and all of my underlying `Views` "jump" until they settle down and get to the correct position.

As explained by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143640/4687402). However, the proposed solution is to use `android:windowActionBarOverlay`. This solves the problem with the glitch, but creates another one, where the pages that are *supposed to* show an `ActionBar` have part of their layout be cut off, because it is now "underneath" the `ActionBar`

Using `actionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30117165/4687402) doesn't help either. The bottom of my activity still glitches.

I know I could use the approach from the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143640/4687402) and just add a margin to the top of the respective pages that are supposed to show an action bar to move the content that's supposed to be visible lower. However this approach seems a little hacky to me, because the way I would do this would involve getting the `height` from the `ActionBar` and adding it to the top of those pages appropriate layout elements at runtime, because I don't know the exact height of the `ActionBar`, which varies from device to device.

I need a clean solution to hide and show the `ActionBar` when showing a specific page, without the Activity glitching around.

PS: I would like to solve this without a third party library

### Edit

Using `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` and `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: I don't know on how to do it with a action. But I suggest you use Toolbar. Then in the each fragment you add the toolbar that needs it.

Comment: @ViatcheslavEhrmann Im not using Fragments, im using Views an Activities. Is there a way to  use Toolbar with that?

Comment: Toolbar is the replacement of the outdated ActionBar. What are the tabs in the ViewPager? Are they activitys or views?

Comment: @ViatcheslavEhrmann The pages in my tabbed ViewPager are Views. I dont think I can add activities there. Not sure how that would work/look or what consequences I would have to expect. Im self taught so sometimes knowledge like that is missing, sorry. 
In any case, changing that would probably way to messy and time consuming anyway.